# How to simulate an exception while updating to test the spring transaction management?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, transactions, spring-transactions

I have under the same spring managed transaction an array of updates as below:

```
someRepositoryA.updateEntityA(...)
someRepositoryB.updateEntityB(...)
someRepositoryC.updateEntityC(...)
```

How can I simulate that `someRepositoryB.updateEntityB(...)` throws an `Exception`? That will allow me to see that the changes made by A were revoked. Since I will test the transaction I cannot mock the repository, but I will use some in-memory database.

Comment: that would not be unit testing, would it?

Comment: Ah I didn't pay attention to the tags :)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't simulate an exception, I'd make something genuinely go wrong.

You're using an in-memory database so you have control of your test data. Also it's a better test (less chance of bad assumptions invalidating your results) if you're recreating a real problem instead of faking out something.

The easiest way to test your transaction would be to have the test create a B with data chosen so that the update will cause a referential integrity constraint to be violated (Do you have any not-null constraints? Otherwise you can introduce an invalid primary key value, by re-using an existing value). The RI violation will cause an exception to get thrown.